# json.net c# - how to set the json dictionary key name?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am serializing a list as JSON, which I can return via my web service.

```
List<grabb> timeline = new List<grabb>();
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;i++)
{
    grabb thisGrabb = new grabb();
    thisGrabb.grabbImage = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["graphimage"].ToString();
    thisGrabb.grabbURL = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["sURL"].ToString();
    thisGrabb.grabbText = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["quote"].ToString();
    thisGrabb.grabbSource = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["source"].ToString();
    thisGrabb.grabbDomainLink = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["domainlink"].ToString();
    thisGrabb.grabbCreateDate = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["createdate"].ToString();
    thisGrabb.grabbPoster = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["username"].ToString();
    thisGrabb.grabbPosterLink = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["userlink"].ToString();
    timeline.Add(thisGrabb);
}

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(timeline, Formatting.Indented);
this.Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
this.Context.Response.Write(json);
```

But, though this is an array, i don't know how to set the dictionary name. I'd like it to return something like

```
[
    { "timeline" : 
        {
        // first list item data in json format 
        },
        { 
            //next list item data in json format}
        }
    }
]
```

whereas presently it returns:

```
[
    {
        // first list item data in json format 
    },
    { 
        //next list item data in json format}
    }
]
```

what am i missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sezerializing the list. That will result in an array. Try using a container class (as an anonymous class in the example):

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { timeline = timeline }, Formatting.Indented);
```

The result will be:

```
{ "timeline" :
[
  {
    // first list item data in json format 
  },
  { 
    //next list item data in json format}
  }
]
}
```

The desired result in your question is not valid JSON.

Comment: thank you, that's done the job. i thought i was missing something simple but I am very new to this. will accept as soon as i can! (yes, sorry was an error at the top, the return as per your answer is what i want/need)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have the structure that you describe, because it is not a legal JSON:

```
[ { "timeline" : { item 1 }, { item 2 } } ]
//                         ^
//                       Error
```

The structure that you want has square brackets on the other side of `:`

```
{ "timeline" : [ { item 1 }, { item 2 } ] }
//             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//         Your code already produces this part
```

You can achieve this effect by adding `timeline` list to a `string` to `object` dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

you could create an anonymous object like this:

```
var ao = new { timeline: timeline }
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ao, Formatting.Indented);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the name of the response set in your web service.
Assuming that you have a simple contract with request/response, you can set the name of the response with the [MessageParameterAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.messageparameterattribute(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    ...
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    [return: MessageParameter(Name = "timeline")]
    Entity DoWork(Entity entity);
    ...
}
```